# Can the Android files app sync local file changes to U1

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android, file-sharing

Does the Android files app sync changes made to local files back to U1? - it seems not to.

I have a bunch of photos sync'd to U1 but when I delete a photo from my device it remains on U1. I'd like the files app to 'sync' i.e. when I delete a file from my device it deletes it from U1.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Android files app does not currently do two-way sync of any files. The only files that are automatically uploaded right now are photos.